# Issues with Foreach with Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, foreach

I'm new to using `foreach` with PHP, so this is probably something obvious as to why this script isn't working. I'm trying to show a list of teammates to the logged in user.

The goal here is that I'm trying to get a list of user names into `<li>` tags, this file will be included within an `<ul>`. The idea is that I look at the `TeamPlayer` table and get all of the `UserIDs` that match the logged in user's current session variable of `TeamID`, then I `JOIN` with my `UserInfo` table to get the `FullName` record for all of the `UserID`'s that match. Place the results into an array and then produce a list of those items to display back to the user.

Can't seem to find where I've gone wrong.

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['TeamID'];

  $teamID = $_SESSION['TeamID'];

  require(dirname(__FILE__) . "/common/config.php"); 

  $query_team  = "SELECT UserInfoTable.FullName
                  FROM TeamPlayer AS TeamPlayerTable 
                  FROM UserInfo AS UserInfoTable 
                  ON TeamPlayerTable.UserID = UserInfoTable.UserID 
                  WHERE TeamPlayerTable.TeamID = '$teamID'";

  $select_team = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query_team);

  $array = mysqli_fetch_array($select_team,MYSQLI_NUM); 

  foreach ($array as $value) { 

    echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";

  }


?>
```

Comment: Your second `FROM` should be some form of `JOIN` (probably `INNER JOIN`). Checking the value of `$select_team` for boolean `false` and checking for errors would have told you this. Also, why would you make table aliases longer than the table name? Seems to defeat the purpose IMHO

Comment: Thanks. Still pretty new to PHP, it was a method shown to me but I didn't like the abbreviations because I found them harder to read over time. When I don't use abbreviations, should it be written as follows: `TeamPlayer.UserID `?

Comment: Yes, you simply use the table name as a prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$query_team  = "SELECT UserInfoTable.*, TeamPlayerTable.*
                FROM Team AS TeamPlayerTable 
                JOIN UserInfo AS UserInfoTable 
                ON TeamPlayerTable.UserID = UserInfoTable.UserID 
                WHERE TeamPlayerTable.TeamID = '$teamID'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using FROM twice, change:

```
...
FROM Team AS TeamPlayerTable 
FROM UserInfo AS UserInfoTable 
...
```

TO

```
...
FROM Team AS TeamPlayerTable 
JOIN UserInfo AS UserInfoTable 
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized I had a few more issues, that I needed to change the Team to TeamPlayer. Also use INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

First, use an actual `JOIN` and prepare a statement with a placeholder for your `$teamID` value...

```
$stmt = $dbhandle->prepare('
    SELECT UserInfo.FullName
    FROM UserInfo
    INNER JOIN TeamPlayer
    ON UserInfo.UserID = TeamPlayer.UserID
    WHERE TeamPlayer.TeamID = ?
'); // THIS IS LITERAL CODE, QUESTION MARK AND ALL

// Check for errors
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($dbhandle->error, $dbhandle->errno);
}
```

This avoids any SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Then bind the value (assuming it's an integer), execute the statement and bind the result ...

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $teamID);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}
$stmt->bind_result($fullName);
```

You don't *have* to use result binding but I find it's the neatest approach.

Now loop over the results...

```
?>
<ul>
    <?php while ($stmt->fetch()) : ?>
    <li><?= htmlspecialchars($fullName) ?><?li>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</ul>
<?php
$stmt->close();
```

Further reading here - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, copied the entire thing and changedo tu the missing variable form the query string. Will keep looking to see where else this code may be broken, but not sure.

Comment: @dvoutt What missing variable? If you mean the `?`, that is meant to be there. It's a prepared statement value placeholder / marker. You obviously didn't read the link at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Totally missed the comment out part, tried it with the '?' and it still didn't work. Not sure what's causing all of these issues.

Comment: @dvoutt My code will not fail silently. You should see uncaught exceptions if anything is not working correctly

Comment: Wish that were the case but I'm not seeing anything in the DOM and the rest of the interface is loading.

Comment: @dvoutt Then you probably have no players in the team stored in session. Do you see an empty `<ul></ul>`? Also, have you got errors displayed (in `php.ini`, set `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = ON` and restart your web server)?

Comment: I have an empty `<ul>` but I have about 10 users in the same team in my local environment. I have checked the settings you referred to and they are all on. I'm running PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP.

Comment: @dvoutt I'd `echo` out the value of `$teamID` and run the query manually in the MySQL console / phpMyAdmin (substituting the `?` for the value of `$teamID`). Just to clarify, is `$teamID` an integer number?

Comment: I'll take a look at this tonight. It's a BIGINT.

Answer (score -1):

Along with Sudhir's answer, you may want to adjust your foreach() loop. I'd recommend:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't seem to resolve it, plus your two variables are not matching.

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing. Assuming you meant to use either `$value` or `$val` (but not both), all you've added is a `$key` variable that is never used